# Loop over subsets of Ansible array

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm working on an Ansible playbook to automate the deployment of some dashboards in Grafana. I have a large list of items that will go into each dashboard, how can I loop over the array, but in sets of 4 elements from the array?

Here's the loop

```
- name: Loop through the topcs to fill in the template with the topic names (replacing the {kafka_topic_placeholder}) and append them to the working file
      shell: sed 's/{kafka_topic_placeholder}/{{ item }}/g' "{{ widget_template_file_path }}" >> "{{ working_file_name }}"
      loop: "{{ kafka_topic_names }}"
```

But I want to run these set of commands:

```
- name: Create the beginning of row
   shell: sed 's/{dashboard_id_placeholder}/{{ dashboard_id }}/g' "{{ dashboard_template_file_part_1 }}" > "{{ final_output_file_name }}"

- name: Add the contents of our working file
   shell: cat "{{ working_file_name }}" >> "{{ final_output_file_name }}"

- name: Add the ending of the row
   shell: sed 's/{overwrite_placeholder}/{{ overwrite_dashboard }}/g' "{{ dashboard_template_file_part_2 }}" >> "{{ final_output_file_name }}"
```

Over this list:

```
kafka_topic_names:
- topic1
- topic2
...
- topicN
```

So I want to end up with as many rows as needed to have sets of 4 topics in each row. I can get it working with everything in a single row, but I'm not sure how to stop during the loop, do the commands I want, then continue the loop from the same place in the array

Answer (score 1):

You can run all the commands in one task like a shell script.

```
- name: Create the beginning of row
  shell: |
    sed 's/{kafka_topic_placeholder}/{{ item }}/g' "{{ widget_template_file_path }}" >> "{{ working_file_name }}"
    sed 's/{dashboard_id_placeholder}/{{ dashboard_id }}/g' "{{ dashboard_template_file_part_1 }}" > "{{ final_output_file_name }}"
    cat "{{ working_file_name }}" >> "{{ final_output_file_name }}"
    sed 's/{overwrite_placeholder}/{{ overwrite_dashboard }}/g' "{{ dashboard_template_file_part_2 }}" >> "{{ final_output_file_name }}"
  loop: "{{ kafka_topic_names }}"
```